# "Expected )" when trying to open an excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently trying to retrieve data from an excel file stored on my server machine. Here's the code.

```
public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelPath)
{
  string connString ="server=D0123;uid=abc;pwd=abc@123;database=MYDB";
  string SqlTable = "xx_fields";
  string excelQuery = "Select FieldName,FieldType,Length,Decimal from [Sheet1$]";

  try {
     string excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+excelPath+";Extended Properties="+"\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

     OleDbConnection oleDbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);
     oleDbconn.Open(); 
     OleDbCommand oleDbcmd = new OleDbCommand(excelQuery,oleDbconn); 
     OleDbDataReader dr = oleDbcmd.ExecuteReader();
     SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString); 
     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = SqlTable;

     while(dr.Read()) {
       bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
     }

     oleDbconn.Close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Error : '" + e.Message + ");</script>");
  }
 }
```

However, I keep getting an error: "Expected )" every time I am trying to open the excel connection string. I tried changing:

```
string excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+excelPath+";Extended Properties="+"\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
```

to

```
string excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+excelPath+";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""";
```

My Excel file is formatted as such:

```
FieldName   FieldType   Length   Decimal
Name         String        10       
Date         Numeric        8        0
Address      String        40 
Age          Numeric        2        0
Price        Numeric        8        2
```

I still get the same error. What gives? On a last note, this C# code is running on a private engine, so no MS Visual Studio cannot be used or other libraries such as MS Office Interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the connection string should be

```
string excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
excelPath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
```

UPDATED:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/
shows this

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

Your `excelPath` should be physical path on your server. You can use `Server.MapPath()` to get the physical path. But, for this function `excelPath` is the parameter, so that, you need to make sure `excelPath` before calling to this function.

Comment: i have tried changing the connection string to yours but it still gives me the same error. Expected ')'

Comment: Can you post the rendered connection string as well?

Comment: I am pretty sure the excelPath is the correct path. the path is obtained from Server.Map() method. Previously, I even tried hardcoding the path but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Patrick, how do I post the rendered connection string? Sorry, quite new at C# and programming in general.

Comment: `string excelQuery = @"Select [FieldName],[FieldType],[Length],[Decimal] from [Sheet1$]";` the SQL also should be escaped

Comment: hi Tun Zarni Kyaw, I have tried just passing in the excel name from my main function and constructing the path in this function itself before the try/catch. also changed my excelQuery as per your suggestion. the same error still occurs.

Comment: "Expected )" by alert on browser? `Response.Write("<script>alert('Error : '" + e.Message + ");</script>");` should be `Response.Write("<script>alert('Error : " + e.Message + "');</script>");`

Comment: Hi Tun, I have corrected the script alert error on the catch loop. But the same problem remains. It keeps breaking off when the oleDBconn.Open() is executed and refusing to open the connection.

Comment: the error "Expected )" isn't descriptive. will you try again with following connection string `string excelConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
excelPath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";`?

Comment: Hi Tun, I have managed to get rid of the "Expected )" error message by removing the e.Message from the codes. However, the program is still catching exceptions with the oleDBconn.Open() method. That conn string was the first I tried. It still wouldn't open my excel.

Comment: no, you should simply do `Response.Write(e.Message)`, and a understand-able message should be seen in the page